# Passing dynamically created SQL Parameters into dapper as an anonymous type

Tags: c#, dapper

Sending dynamically created SQL Parameters into dapper.

**I usually do the following when sending multiple params to dapper:**

```
return connection.Query<Customer>(sql.ToString(), 
    new
    {
        Status = status,
        ZipCodes = zipCodes,
        Types = type
    }).ToList();
```

However I need to figure out a way to dynamically generate these parameters based on a list of key value pairs that I will have.

I want to be able to loop through a list and create the params to pass into dapper dynamically.

Comment: you need a `Dictionary<string,object>` rite ? because there is name & value(s) ?

Comment: @Shyju Correct. I have always passed my params into dapper like the above. How can I pass params in based on logic? There has to be another way.

Comment: Show us what kind of data you have (add to the question please)

Comment: @Shyju pretend it is a dictionary with key value pairs. I need to pass it into dapper as the params.

Comment: Do you have different version of the query because you want to pass variable number of parameters .rite ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how I would modify what you've got.  In this snippet, Params is your dictionary.

```
DynamicParameters dbParams = new DynamicParameters();
dbParams.AddDynamicParams(params);
return connection.Query<Customer>(sql.ToString(),dbParams).ToList();
```